# NSTableCellView not displaying its stringValue

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

The cells themselves appear with the amount of items in the `items` array (I can select them), but they don't have the title assigned to them.

```swift
...

let items: Array<String>? = // contains only strings (also without control characters)

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
    
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return self.items!.count
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
        cell.textField?.stringValue = self.items![row]
        return cell
    }
        
    return nil
}

...
```

Comment: Is `cell.textField` `nil`? Is `cell.textField?.stringValue = self.items![row]` executed?

Comment: I just tested it and interestingly the code within the 'if' is not executed, is there something wrong with an 'if let' there? @Willeke

Comment: Are the identifier of the cell view and the table column the same or both Automatic? Is the cell view in the storyboard/xib a `NSTableCellView`? Any Cocoa Bindings? Is the table view view-based?

Comment: The column identifier is automatic, and the cell uses it as well `tableColumn!.identifier `. Within the 'Table Column' in the xib there's only one NSTextFieldCell (do I even need that?). The table view is added on a custom view and bound to the swift file. @Willeke

Comment: Almost forgot: The table view is view based.

Comment: Solved the problem myself, see my answer; Thanks for making me check!

Comment: Never never ever declare a data source array as optional . Declare it as empty array `Array<String>()` and remove the pointless exclamation marks.

Comment: The array contents is retrieved from another class, that returns an empty array eventually @vadian

Comment: Yes but an empty array and an optional are two different things. And as you force unwrap the array anyway an optional makes no sense at all.

Comment: I see, will change it to the better ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had to select the table view on the view hierarchy and set the content mode to cell based and back to view based. Now it works.